# Find 2nd largest value in an array that has duplicates of the largest integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to find the second largest number in an array of numbers, but the greatest number appears twice, so I can't just remove it from the array and select the new highest number.

`array = [0, 3, 2, 5, 5]` (therefore `3` is the 2nd largest value)

I have this code where I can explicitly return 3, but it wouldn't work on other arrays:

```
    function getSecondLargest(nums) {

      var sorted_array = nums.sort(function (a,b) {return a - b;});
      var unique_sorted_array = sorted_array.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
})

    return unique_sorted_array[unique_sorted_array.length - 2];
}

return unique_sorted_array[unique_sorted_array.length - 2];
```

If I wanted to make it more dynamic, is there a way that I could identify the greatest value of the array, then compare that against each iteration of the array?

I was thinking that something along the lines of:

```
var greatestNum = sortedArray[-1]

while(greatestNum != i) do {
  //check for the first number that doesn't equal greatestNum
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to handle the case when all elements of the array are equal? Or when  array length is less than 2?

Comment: That won't be necessary, but that might be good for anyone looking this up in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply create a [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) first and than [**sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in descending and take the 1st index element

```js
let array = [0, 3, 2, 5, 5]

let op = [...new Set(array)].sort((a,b) => b-a)[1]

console.log(op)
```

For those who thinks in terms of efficiency. this is the best way IMO

```js
let array = [0, 3, 2, 5, 5]

let max = -Infinity
let secondMax = -Infinity

for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  if(array[i] > max){
    secondMax = max
    max = array[i]
  }
}

console.log(secondMax)
```

Comment: Could also do `.sort().reverse()` if your lazy

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes but that's doing the same thing twice when you can do in one go

Comment: @Code Maniac +1 for the second one.It was new for me

Comment: Thanks @CodeManiac - really concise answer and I appreciate that you added your solution in the "Run code snippet"

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend doing something more like

```
const nums = [0, 3, 2, 5, 5];
nums.sort(function (a,b) {return b - a;})

for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
  if (nums[0] !== nums[i]) {
    return nums[i];
  }
}
```

which should be a lot more efficient (especially in terms of memory) than converting to a set and back...

Comment: On side note: When you talk about speed and performance, than you should do it even without sort. in this case it is possible to use just two variable and simple for loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var intArray = stringArray.map(nums); // now let's sort and  take the second element :

var second = intArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[1];

};
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to do this using **Math.max()**. Here's the simplest way to do this.

```js
const getSecondLargest = function (arr) {
  const largest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (largest === arr[i]) {
      arr[i] = -Infinity;
    }
  }
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
};
console.log(getSecondLargest([3, 5, 9, 9, 9])); //5
```

Side note: Math.max() don't take an array, so we have to use Math.max.apply() to pass the array in the function. **-Infinity** is smaller than any negative finite number.